# Volume not showing in citation ISO 690 style

Tags: citing

I am using bibtex to cite in my thesis and the ISO 690 citation style. However, the volume does not show in bibliography. Can anyone help me ?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[style=iso-numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
```

and the citation input

```
@book{reynolds1, 
title={Earthship: How to build your own},
volume ={1},
author={Michael E. Reynolds},
ISBN={9780962676703},
location ={Taos},
year={1990},
publisher={Solar Survival Press},
}
```

Comment: Please exatend your example to a full example that others can copy and use as is. Hint: modern latex include the `filecontents` env which can be used to provide the `references.bib` from the latex file, thus having only one MWE.

Comment: `volume` should be used for multivolume books. I think you want to use `edition` instead.

Comment: no it is a volume it is a multivolume book

Answer (score 2):

The volume is not included in `iso.bbx` for the `book` entry type. I'm not sure if that is on purpose. However, you can copy the definition for `book` and add the volume part from another style, for example from the default `standard.bbx`. The default file has the following code for volume:

```
\iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
```

which means that the volume and part number are printed if there is no `maintitle`.

In the MWE below I have added this part between `edition` and `names:subsidiary` (editor and translator) in the definition copied from `iso.bbx`. I don't know if this is according to ISO 690 but it does print the volume.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[left=1cm,right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[style=iso-numeric]{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{names:primary}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{multi:titles}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{medium-type}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{names:subsidiary}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{location+publisher+date}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{version}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{urldate}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{identifier}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{availability+access}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{location}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \iftoggle{bbx:totalpages}
    {\printfield{pagetotal}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\addbibresource{references.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{reynolds1} is a volume from a book series.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]